# Basics of C++ with Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I have read about Arduino, and how it uses a language that is similar but not equal to C. I am very familiar with C++, and I was wondering how one would do basic tasks with the Arduino, such as communicating with the I/O pins. I figure that one would need the memory address to the pins, and then do something like this for a "flashing led":

```
int main()    {
    while (1)    {
        bool * out_pin = /* Whatever that memory address was for that pin */;
        *out_pin = 1;
        // Some sort of sleep function? (I only know of "windows.h"'s "Sleep" function)
        *out_pin = 0;
    }
    return 0; // Kind of unneeded, I suppose, but probably compiler errors otherwise.
}
```

I'm probably really wrong: that's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: Close. The pins don't have memory addresses (they're [register](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation) mapped, not memory mapped). Generally, the compiler already maps them to variables for you. So you just do `pin_name = pin_value;` (like `PORTD = 7;`) and the compiler does the magic.

Comment: Thank you so much for that (quick!) answer. I am curious this though: what type is your "`pin_name`" Is it a `bool *` or something else? And can you later do what I did modifying the value (and such)?

Comment: It's a keyword for a register. It behaves like a variable. When the compiler sees `PORTD = 7;` is compiles it to the necessary assembly code to load a 7 into the PORTD register. When it sees `i = PORTD;` is loads the value from the PORTD register and stored it in the variable `i`. The compiler just makes it work.

Comment: Your use of web-searches seems to be failing, one of the first examples on the official Arduino page is a [blinking led](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Blink).

Comment: @Joachim: That is in the Arduino language: I figured it was different with C++, even with the Arduino library. I searched the web far before asking this question. It has been answered already. (But I can't mark it as answered until two days after asking it).

Comment: The "Arduino language" is actually normal C++ with some limitations (like no `new`/`delete`). If you are familiar with C++ you can still use that knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is copied from the comments below my question. David Schwartz answered my questions:

> Close. The pins don't have memory addresses (they're register mapped, not memory mapped). Generally, the compiler already maps them to variables for you. So you just do pin_name = pin_value; (like PORTD = 7;) and the compiler does the magic. – David Schwartz 7 mins ago
>
> [PORTD's] a keyword for a register. It behaves like a variable. When the compiler sees PORTD = 7; is compiles it to the necessary assembly code to load a 7 into the PORTD register. When it sees i = PORTD; is loads the value from the PORTD register and stored it in the variable i. The compiler just makes it work. – David Schwartz 2 mins ago

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pinMode(your_pin) to activate the IO pin. Then you can use digital/analog write/read to communicate with them

Comment: What library is pinMode in? I thought that that was an "Arduino Programming Language" function. Is there a library where I can get that for C++?

Comment: pinMode is indeed in the arduino standard library. I haven't heard of a pure C++ equivalent